# Cannot execute Groovy Maven Plugin as a goal

Tags: java, maven, groovy, maven-3, pom.xml

I am using Apache Maven 3.3.9 with the Groovy Maven plugin. Here is the relevant section of the pom.xml (the inlined Groovy script is just fictional):

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.codehaus.gmaven</groupId>
    <artifactId>groovy-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>2.0</version>
    <executions>
      <execution>
        <id>myGroovyPlugin</id>
        <phase>prepare-package</phase>
        <goals>
          <goal>execute</goal>
        </goals>
        <configuration>
          <source>
    log.info('Test message: {}', 'Hello, World!')
          </source>
        </configuration>
      </execution>
    </executions>
</plugin>
```

If I am calling `mvn install` the inline Groovy script gets called by the plugin as part of the prepare-package phase and works just fine. But if I try to call the plugins' goal directly via `mvn groovy:execute` I get the following error message:

> [ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.codehaus.gmaven:groovy-maven-plugin:2.0:execute (default-cli) on project exercise02: The parameters 'source' for goal org.codehaus.gmaven:groovy-maven-plugin:2.0:execute are missing or invalid -> [Help 1]

Comment: Right, because you're directly invoking the goal without the proper configuration instead of using the execution here which has the configuration attached.

Comment: that is, as @chrylis pointed out, however I couldn't find any relevant duplicate on Stack Overflow for this issue, although I believe there are many similar questions.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The error you are getting is already pointing at the issue: the plugin couldn't not find the `source` configuration option because indeed it is only configured within the `myGroovyPlugin` execution, that is, only in the `execution` scope and not as a global configuration.

This is the main difference between `configuration` element outside the `executions` (global configuration for all executions of the plugin (even from command line) and within an `execution` (configuration only applied to that particular goal execution).

To fix the issue you should move the `configuration` element outside the `executions` section in this case, since the plugin is not a plugin invoked during [default bindings](http://maven.apache.org/ref/3.3.9/maven-core/default-bindings.html) by Maven, it would be enough and not have impact on your build: it will be still used during the `myGroovyPlugin` execution AND from explicit executions from command line.

From [Maven POM reference](https://maven.apache.org/pom.html#Plugins), the `configuration` within an `execution`:

> confines the configuration to this specific list of goals, rather than all goals under the plugin.

---

To make it clear, you should change it to the following:

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.codehaus.gmaven</groupId>
    <artifactId>groovy-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>2.0</version>
    <executions>
      <execution>
        <id>myGroovyPlugin</id>
        <phase>prepare-package</phase>
        <goals>
          <goal>execute</goal>
        </goals>
      </execution>
    </executions>
    <configuration>
      <source>log.info('Test message: {}', 'Hello, World!')</source>
    </configuration>        
</plugin>
```

As such the `configuration` will become a global configuration and applied to both command line executions and declared `executions`.

---

Since you are using Maven **3.3.9**, you could also make use of a slightly more verbose pattern to [invoke directly a specific configuration of an execution](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/MNG-5768):

```
mvn groovy:execute@myGroovyPlugin
```

This pattern is useful in cases where you really don't want a global configuration because you don't want to impact other (often default) executions of a certain plugin and you really want to use a specific isolated configuration both in an execution and from command line.

Comment: This is absolutely it! Thank you. The curious thing is that [GMaven's documentation](https://groovy.github.io/gmaven/groovy-maven-plugin/execute.html#Source) shows examples with `executions/execution/configuration/source`, which even if copied across exactly, won't work. Moving that to `configuration/source`, as you say, solved it for me.